# Async props pass in React: How to pass a key to update redux store in react? [First from the higher component and then from redux store]

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two react components: `TextDropdowns` and `TextDropDown`. `TextDropdowns` have multiple `TextDropDown` component with a different data:

```
const TextDropDownKeys = DummyData.map((elem) => {
            return <TextDropDown 
                             key = {elem.UniqueIdentifier}
                             Values = {elem.Values}
                             PlaceHolderText = {elem.PlaceHolderText} 
                             UniqueIdentifier = {elem.UniqueIdentifier}
                             AllowMultiSelect = {elem.MultiSelect}
                             isMainHeaderRequired = {elem.isMainHeaderRequired}
                             MainHeader = {elem.isMainHeader}
                             MainHeaderStyling = {elem.isMainHeaderStyling}
                             />
        });
```

Here is how my store looks like:

```
const initState = {

    ClearAllFilters: false,
    DateFilter: {
        isFilterApplied: false,
        dateData: new Date(),
    },

    key1: 
                                {
                                    Values: ["val1" "val2", "val3"],
                                    SelectedValues: [],
                                    isFilterApplied: false,
    },
    key2: 
                                {
                                    Values: ["val1" "val2", "val3"],
                                    SelectedValues: [],
                                    isFilterApplied: false,
    },
    
    error: false,

};
```

My `TextDropDown` needs to be connected to a redux store as shown below:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        FilterDropDownData: state.sideBar[this.props.key].Values,
        isSelected: state.sideBar[this.props.KeyValue].isFilterApplied,
    }
  
  }
```

Now here comes the challenging problem, I am passing a unique `key` through props in `TextDropDowns`, but since I am reusing `TextDropDown` again and again I need to update the data of the corresponding identifier only and not for the other keys.

Since both the props are passed at the same time to `TextDropDown` (One from `TextDropDowns`, hence I get this error, I need to pass the props from both ends (As one of them is component dependent and the other is entire app dependent) and so I am facing this ambiguity. Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the components props to the mapStateToProps function:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
return {
    FilterDropDownData: state.sideBar[props.key].Values,
    isSelected: state.sideBar[props.KeyValue].isFilterApplied,
}
```

}

Be aware that you cannot use the context `this.props` because the mapStateToProps has a different context (=different `this`).

Comment: Okay but how do I define props will it automatically take the props that were defined by the higher order component?

Comment: thank you very much for your time and answer. This solved my problem.

Comment: It will take the props of the component that uses this mapStateToProps function. In other words: Whichever component you connect to the Redux store those props will be used.